# Schedule a scripted pipeline job with Parameters that already has "choice parameters"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I have a pipeline script as below

```
node('web') {
    stage('Test Parameter') {
        container('alpine') {
            properties([pipelineTriggers([
                            cron('H/2 * * * *'),
                            parameterizedCron('H/2 * * * * % data=xml;environment=prod')]
                                        ),
                        ])
            script {
                PARAMS = input id: 'param', message: 'List of Parameters',
                parameters: [
                choice(choices: 'xml\ncsv', description: 'Select a dataset', name: 'data'),
                choice(choices: 'qa\nprod', description: 'Select an environment', name: 'environment')
                ]
                data = "${PARAMS['data']}"
                environment = "${PARAMS['environment']}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is `schedule` this `pipeline` job so that it runs automatically. So I did `parameterizedCron('H/2 * * * * % data=xml;environment=prod')`... But still when the job get's triggered by `timer` it get's stuck at `input requested` as you can see I have `choice` parameter in the script.

How do I get the job provide the input automatically?

Comment: Have you figured this one out?

Answer (score 0):

You could include the input step inside a timeout block so that if there is no input the job will continue with the defaults.
By the way, in choices, the first option will be considered as the default automatically.

[Here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922148-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-with-timeout-that-continues-if-timeout-is-reached-using-a-default-value) you can find and example for a timeout block.

Comment: I don't want the job to run with default option. I want the job to run with the option provided inside `parameterizedCron`

Comment: Okay, still you can include a timeout for the user input as I have mentioned above. Then it will stop after the timeout and your parameters will be applied.